# Regex specific password restrictions

Tags: c++, regex

I need to validate password to fulfill at least three combinations of these rules:
`Upper case, lower case, number, special char`
The password also needs to be at least 8 characters long.

**EDIT**
*I know these password restrictions are contraproductive, it's a request, not my naive idea of getting stronger passwords.*

Example of valid passwords:

```
Password3   // Upper case, lower case, number
Password!   // Upper case, lower case, special
password3!  // Lower case, number, special
PASSWORD3!  // Upper case, number, special
Password3!  // Upper case, lower case, number, special
```

Example of invalid passwords:

```
password    // Only lower case
password3   // Only lower case and number
password!   // Only lower case and special
Password    // Only Upper case and lower case
Pw3!        // Too short
```

Here is a regex I wrote:

```
(?=.*[A-z\d]+)(?=.*[A-z@!?]+)(?=.*[a-z\d@!?]+)(?=.*[A-Z\d@!?]+)[A-z\d@!?]{8,}
```

Hopefuly, I know why this regex matches invalid passwords too, if so, how can I say then, that the expression must contain everything from the group and not just one match?

Comment: Why not just scan through the password linearly and check each of the requirement as you go through it?  If you make it to the end and one or more is missing then you know you do not have a valid string.

Comment: I would recommend not bothering with such policies. They're no longer effective against modern password cracking techniques which already account for about every simple trick you can think of. They just add more work for you and more ways to get in the user's way. Either use a professionally made [password strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) checker, or don't bother. Consider asking on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) about this.

Comment: At least 3 *combinations* of these rules requires a huge regex with alternations. Better split these into several smaller ones.

Comment: @Schwern, That's what I was telling in my company as well. It so contraproductive, but I can't really do much about it. They want these restrictions and I just have to do it.

Comment: @ProXicT Also I don't see how your question is actually related to the [tag:c++] tag. See the first sentence in the tag info wiki: _"C++ is a general-purpose programming language based on C. **Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler**."_ You don't show any c++ code. Removing the tag again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The `C++` tag is to prevent answers for specific language/engine, which are only situable for such language. Perl regexes are somewhat different than other regexes, that's why I included the `C++` tag and I'm standing behind it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I agree with ProXicT - [tag:regex] tag should never stand alone. A regex will be code that will be compiled by `std::regex_search` of C++, and is fair target for [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: My mistake, the OP did not quote from [tag:regex] tag. Here is that quote, that actually takes the form of the rule, not just a recommendation: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool".

Comment: Please take this to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that your problem is a kinda hard one. So I would split it into more understandable pieces. That will help *so much*. Look at this example I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(){

    bool upper_case = false; //saves the result if upper-case characters were found.
    bool lower_case = false; //same for lower-case
    bool number_case = false; //...
    bool special_char = false;


    std::regex upper_case_expression{ "[A-Z]+" }; //here is the very simple expression for upper_case search
    std::regex lower_case_expression{ "[a-z]+" }; //for lower-case
    std::regex number_expression{ "[0-9]+" }; //...
    std::regex special_char_expression{ "[@!?]+"};


    std::string pw;


    bool done = false; //let's assume we're not done

    do{ //do ask-for-password as long were not done

        std::cout << "Type in a valid password: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, pw); //get input

        if (pw.length() <= 8){ //too short!
            std::cout << "Invalid password! Try again . . .\n\n";
        }
        else{

            upper_case = std::regex_search(pw, upper_case_expression); //save the result, if the expression was found.
            lower_case = std::regex_search(pw, lower_case_expression); //....
            number_case = std::regex_search(pw, number_expression);
            special_char = std::regex_search(pw, special_char_expression);

            //like: sum_of_positive_results = 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 (true/false as an integer)
            int sum_of_positive_results = upper_case + lower_case + number_case + special_char; 

            if (sum_of_positive_results < 3){ //not enough booleans were true!
                std::cout << "Invalid password! Try again . . .\n\n";
            }
            else{ //otherwise it's valid!
                std::cout << "That's a valid Password!" << std::endl;
                done = true;
            }
        }

    } while (!done);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Type in a valid password: password
Invalid password! Try again . . .

Type in a valid password: Password
Invalid password! Try again . . .

Type in a valid password: password!
Invalid password! Try again . . .

Type in a valid password: password3
Invalid password! Try again . . .

Type in a valid password: not valid!
Invalid password! Try again . . .

Type in a valid password: Password!
That's a valid Password!
```

As you can see, that's way nicer and easier to follow. I hope that helped you!

Comment: I know how to roll up some C++ code to make this work, as I said in comments, I was just wondering, if there is a way to do it with a single regex, that's why I asked, maybe I should have specified that in my question. Thanks for the effort though! I will mark your answer as a solution, since I will go with a similar way of validating it.

Comment: It's bad UX for the password checker to not tell the user why the password failed the check. Very frustrating. It's also easier to hold onto a single boolean flag which gets flipped false when a check fails than to count up the number of successes; very easy to add a check and forget to update the proper count. Even easier: put it in a function and return on the first check failure.

Comment: Yes it's bad for telling "not valid password" but absolutely necessary in this case. We don't want a valid password, we want to look if the string fits the 4 expressions, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get this out of the way, [password strength checkers like this do not work](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/best-password-strength-checker).

> In theory, password strength checkers do not work. That's because the strength of a password does not depend upon the password value (which you give to the checker) but upon the password generation process (which you do not formalize often, let alone enter in the checker).

Here's Sophos on the subject: ["Why you can’t trust password strength meters"](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/03/02/why-you-cant-trust-password-strength-meters/) and ["Why you STILL can’t trust password strength meters"](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/17/why-you-still-cant-trust-password-strength-meters/).

> Simple password meters check the length and entropy of the password and have checklists for the kinds of things that users are advised to include in their passwords; mixtures of upper and lower case letters, numbers and special characters, for example.
>
> That helps determine a password’s ability to withstand a brute force attack (an attacker making guesses at random), but being resistant to brute force attacks is only useful if that’s what an attacker is going to do, and it probably isn’t.

Here's Concordia University, ["From Very Weak to Very Strong: Analyzing Password-Strength Meters"](https://madiba.encs.concordia.ca/%7Ex_decarn/papers/password-meters-ndss2014.pdf).

> In our large-scale empirical analysis, it is evident
> that the commonly-used meters are highly inconsistent, fail
> to provide coherent feedback on user choices, and sometimes
> provide strength measurements that are blatantly misleading.

All the breeches of password databases over the years have given attackers years to study hundreds of millions of real passwords and look for exploitable patterns. `P4ssw0rd!` isn't going to work anymore, they're on to our tricks. They know about replacing `a` with `4`. They know about sticking a punctuation character at the end. They know about upper casing the first letter of a dictionary word. Attackers use low cost GPUs as little super computers to do extreme parallel processing to try all of these tricks.

More important is to measure password entropy, basically how hard it is to match your password with an existing pattern. How random looking is it? Humans are really bad at creating entropy. Writing an entropy checker is beyond the scope of this answer.

***The only way to make a secure password is to randomly generate a new one for each account*** using the maximum available length, and storing it in a password vault. ***Any system which involves making up passwords in your head and remembering them has already been broken***.

Point is: don't bother. You're closing the door LONG after the horse has left the barn.

Now onto the question.

---

## Do it in multiple regexes

You *could* do it as one regex, but then you'd have an unreadable, unmaintainable mess. If you ever wanted to add to it, good luck.

The other reason is it's difficult to figure out from one check *why* the password failed. Nothing is more annoying than being told your password is invalid but not *why*. Be sure to design your password checking function so it says which check failed.

The basic pattern is to write a series of checks for it to fail. If it passes all those, it passes. Here's a sketch in Perl.

```
sub is_invalid_password {
    my $password = shift;

    # Instead of hard coding the wording of the message,
    # use constants. This lets the UX person handle the
    # wording. Also helps internationalization.
    return NEEDS_UPPER_CASE unless $password =~ /[A-Z]/;
    return NEEDS_LOWER_CASE unless $password =~ /[a-z]/;

    ...and so on...

    return 0;
}
```

It's checking for an *invalid* password so it can return the error constant on failure. This makes it much simpler to use. Just make sure all the constants are true values and you can write:

```
if( my $reason = is_invalid_password($password) ) {
    # Don't just say the password is invalid, say why.
    display_invalid_password_reason($reason);
}
else {
    store_password($password);
}
```

The regexes are...

1. `/[A-Z]/`
2. `/[a-z]/`
3. `/[0-9]/`
4. `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`

Oh, wait... Unicode. You have to use [POSIX character classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes) else you'll reject `Élan1;`. These are how Perl does it, your language may vary.

1. `/[[:upper:]]/`
2. `/[[:lower:]]/`
3. `/[[:digit:]]/`
4. `/[^[:alnum:]]/`

It's very easy to do this wrong and annoy the user. It's a bit of work to do it right. It's not adding any security. This is why I recommend don't bother.

Comment: As I edited my question few minutes ago, I think, you can remove the prelude about password security. I already told you that in comments of my question. I know any password restrictions but length are bad, it is not my idea to require such stupid rules for password.
I also specified C++ tag to my question to prevent answers in other languages. It's enough for me to know, that one regex is simply not the way I should solve this problem, that was the whole point of asking. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: @ProXicT If you ask me for a gun, you're going to get a safety briefing (or a better analogy, a bullet proof vest that I know does not work). A bad idea is a bad idea, even if you're ordered to do it, and I cannot in good conscience answer the question without that caveat. And the answer is not just for you, but for anyone else who finds it. You might be able to use that info to countermand the order. As for C++, the language doesn't matter, the technique is the same.

Comment: The point here is, that I only asked the question to find out, if there is a way to do the task with only one regular expression. I already got the answer I'm happy with. I didn't ask about the security problem, since I know this is a stupid idea, I'm just too little man here to convince the others. I really appreciate your effort, but the prelude about the security is more situable for [Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ProXicT I laid the answer out so you can skip the security advice if you wish, but which you could use to convince your boss it's a bad idea, perhaps by pointing them at this discussion. I went into UX and Unicode issues you may not have considered. Do with this information as you will. But since you're not happy with your free expert advice and bonus content, I will happily give you triple your money back. Finally, *this answer is not just for you*, it's for everyone else who stumbles onto SO with the same bad idea, many of which don't know it's a bad idea.

Comment: I told you I appreciate your effort, but this belong much more to Security SE and there the problem is solved. The question was about different problem. "It's for everyone who stumbles onto SO with the same bad idea" - That's why I mentioned that in my question.